# Thingsboard emails not sending on alarm

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to get an email to be sent whenever an alarm is created for a device. I have followed the tutorial at this link: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/send-email/. The alarm is being created successfully but no email is being sent, not even to my spam folders.

I am using a local copy of thingsboard and when I configured my system SMTP settings, the test email sent successfully. I am using the system SMTP settings for the Send Email node, and I filled in my email for the To field in the To Email node.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting the email to send?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while fooling around with TB. In my case the email was  **received** by SendGrid but it was being **blocked** by the gmail server which can be viewed in the SendGrid activity tab. Hence it never made it to the recipient. The reason it was getting blocked is I was using info@testemail.org in **FROM** field for email. I changed it to a **valid email** and it started working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

enable the debug mode in the email node in rule engine and go to events tab to see the input/output of the node to see what is the response from the email server or if the email server is responding at all.
I've tried the guide and it is working like a charm, the debug mode helped me solving all the problems I faced.